# How do I copy files in a build chain in msbuild

Tags: msbuild

Say I have project A and project B where B depends on A. Project A contains some .py files. A copies those py files to output folder $(Outdir) with the common PostProcessBuild target. B then copies its files and As output files to B's $(Outdir) with PostProcessBuild. Currently in order for the B's output to contain both A and B's files, I must run msbuild twice.

How can I update my target to run msbuild only once and output both A and B's files in B's output directory?

Copy target:

```xml
    <Target Name="PostProcessBuild" 
        Inputs="@(ProjectOutput)"
        Outputs="@(ProjectOutput->'%(Destination)%(FileName)%(Extension)')">
        <Message Text="Post-Processing Build" />
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(ProjectOutput)" DestinationFolder="%(ProjectOutput.Destination)"/>
    </Target>
```

Project A:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Build.NoTargets" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectOutput Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\pySpark\*" Destination="$(OutDir)\%(RecursiveDir)\"/>
        <ProjectOutput Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\pySpark\**" Destination="$(OutDir)\%(RecursiveDir)\"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Project B:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Build.NoTargets" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">     
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="$(INETROOT)\sources\dev\Projects\xplat\A\A.xpproj" />
        <ProjectOutput Include="$(AllProjectsRoot)\A\*;$(AllProjectsRoot)\A\**" Destination="$(OutDir)\%(RecursiveDir)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some questions:

- Are the two projects in a solution (.sln file) and are you building the .sln?
- Have you run MSBuild with the -v:d or -v:diag switch to increase the verbosity of the logging output?